# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos de una tabla en un dropdown list en Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Buenas. Tengo el problema de que quiero listar determinados datos de una BD MySQL en Codeigniter y no me devuelve absolutamente nada.

Les dejo el código que estoy usando:

**loginController.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class loginController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('categoriasModel');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $datos['arrCategorias'] = $this->categoriasModel->get_categorias();


        $this->load->view('login_index', $datos);
    }


}
```

**categoriasModel.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class categoriasModel extends CI_Model {

    public $variable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function get_categorias(){


    $query = $this->db-> query('SELECT id_categoria,nombre_categoria FROM categorias');


    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $arrDatos[htmlspecialchars($row->id_categoria, ENT_QUOTES)] = htmlspecialchars($row->nombre_categoria, ENT_QUOTES);
        }


        $query->free_result();
        return $arrDatos;
     }

}
```

**login_index.php**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Disquerias La Roberta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        body {
          padding-top: 40px;
          padding-bottom: 40px;
          background-color: #eee;
        }

        .form-signin {
          max-width: 330px;
          padding: 15px;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
        .form-signin .login {
          margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .form-signin .login {
          font-weight: normal;
        }
        .form-signin .form-control {
          position: relative;
          height: auto;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
             -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                  box-sizing: border-box;
          padding: 10px;
          font-size: 16px;
        }
        .form-signin .form-control:focus {
          z-index: 2;
        }
        .form-signin input[type="text"] {
          margin-bottom: -1px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        }
        .form-signin input[type="password"] {
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          border-top-left-radius: 0;
          border-top-right-radius: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Iniciar sesion</h2>
        <label for="inputLogin" class="sr-only">Login</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="login">
            <select class="form-control">
            <?php
foreach ($arrCategorias as $i => $categoria)
   echo '<option values="'.$i.'">'.$categoria.'</option>';
?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Entrar</button>
      </form>

    </div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero una respuesta ya que desde hace varios dias ando con este problema. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Roberto, podrias depurar el código e indicarnos exactamente en que  parte es la que no devuelve nada, hasta donde si devuelve la data y en que parte se pierde? Luego puedes actualizar tu pregunta colocando solo el código que falla. Por favor lee: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Posiblemente sea un problema con tu consulta a la base de datos, prueba a usar phpMyAdmin o similares para examinar tus tablas y ver qué ocurre.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta las "llaves" en el `foreach(){}`, también puedes hacerlo de esta manera.

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Seleccione un usuario</option>
    <?php foreach ($data as $row) {?>
    <option value="<?=$row->id_usuario;?>"><?=$row->v_nombre;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Está raro que no esté pintando nada. Podrías retornar un `print_r($data)` en lugar de regresar la vista, esto para saber si en verdad trae la info de la base de datos.

Lo otro que vi es que posiblemente en el Modelo `categoriasModel::get_categorias`, la variable `$arrDatos` puede llegar perderse por estar dentro del contexto del foreach y por ello no recibas datos.

La otra y que seria muy raro es que no hayas configurado la conexión a la base (suele pasar)